# Regex to match strings which only contain alphabetic characters python

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regex using re to match only alphabetic characters, I have tried many things but nothing works. What I am trying to do is like the following:

```
re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+', str)
```

This should return true only if it matches with a string of length >1 and contains only alphabetic characters however it currently matches with all strings including '', '●', '1' etc

Thanks

Kabeer

Comment: Try adding anchors: `re.match(r'[a-zA-Z]+$', str)`

Comment: `re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$', str)` or `re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z]{2,}$', str)` (it is not quite clear about *of length >1*).

Comment: Also don't need a regex if you just want a bool answer `all(i in string.ascii_letters for i in str)`

Comment: Guys, are you answering the question or commenting? Oh nvm I didn't see it is already closed

Comment: You can also do this without regex by doing, `myStr.isalpha()`